# Method Headers in Groovy?

Tags: methods, groovy

I am currently learning about method headers and how to implement them

I see the most prevalent use of method headers are in C and Java

As I using groovy predominantly, I'm wondering if method headers are applicable in groovy

In the below code example

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def call() {
   def commitMessage = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s')
   def projectName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'basename -s .git `git config --get 
   remote.origin.url`').trim()
   def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER
   def gitCommitHash = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
   def branchName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
   def json_str = JsonOutput.toJson([commitMessage: "$commitMessage", gitCommitHash: "$gitCommitHash", 
   projectName: "$projectName", buildNumber:"$buildNumber", branchName: "$branchName"])
   def json_beauty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json_str)
   return json_beauty
}
```

How could I implement a method header for this library?

Comment: `def call()` is what literature describe as method header. I am not really sure, what you question is?

Comment: thank you for the clarification

Comment: "Method headers" in Java and Groovy are not like in C, where you might actually *need* a separate method header (apart from the method definition itself). `def call()` is the method header, although it lacks a return type.

Comment: `def` implies `Object` as return value declaration - i'ts not great style though

Answer (score 1):

"Method headers" in Java and Groovy are not like in C, where you might actually need a separate method header (apart from the method definition itself). def call() is the method header, although it lacks a return type. – Dave Newton